# Printing the "\" key in Java using System.out.println

Tags: java

I am trying to use the `\` key in part of my output.

Current searches via google are not proving to be successful, perhaps I'm calling it the wrong thing (back slash, escape character, etc.) I cannot find anywhere the code or how to make eclipse understand I want to actually print that character, and that I'm not attempting some sort of escape code.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You have to double-escape it, since it is the escape character:

`System.out.println("\\");`

Comment: I love it when it's that simple. Thanks so much.

Comment: Actually, it's just "escape" rather than double-escape. You double-escape when (for example) you create something for a program that needs escaping: `String cmd = "echo \\\\n";`.

Answer (score 1):

Alogn with '\', also there are characters which are required to be used with escape sequence.

\' - Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.

\" - Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.

\\ - Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.

When an escape sequence is encountered in a print statement, the compiler interprets it accordingly. For example, if you want to put quotes within quotes you must use the escape sequence, \", on the interior quotes. To print the sentence

She said "Hello!" to me.

you would write

```
System.out.println("She said \"Hello!\" to me.");
```